# Changing dependency property on behavior

Tags: wpf, xaml

I Have a Behavior that I created a dependency property on it, this behavior is used in an item template of a ListBox.
What I need to do is change the value in the dependency property when the ListBoxItem is selected.
I tried to give the Behavior a name in the Xaml but the trigger didn't recognize it (compilation error).
I tried creating a 0 sized grid, changing the color of the background of that grid in the trigger and binding the dependency property to the background of that grid, it took the first value but didn't update when the trigger changed the background.

Behavior class:

```
public class DragToCenter : Behavior<FrameworkElement>
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CenteredTextColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "CenteredTextColor",
        typeof(Color),
        typeof(DragToCenter),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(Brushes.Black.Color, CenteredTextColorPropertyChanged));

    private static void CenteredTextColorPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DragToCenter lBase = d as DragToCenter;
        if (lBase != null)
        {
            d.SetValue(CenteredTextColorProperty, e.NewValue);
            lBase.DrowImage();
        }
    }

    public Color CenteredTextColor
    {
        get
        {
            return (Color)GetValue(CenteredTextColorProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(CenteredTextColorProperty, value);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
            // Do something
    }

    private void DrowImage()
    {
            // Do something that changes the view so it will be visible if this is triggered
    }
```

XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding DisplayValues}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid x:Name="CenterText" Height="0" Width="0" Background="Gray"/>
                        <Border>
                                <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                        <b:DragToCenter CenteredTextColor="{Binding ElementName=CenterText, Path=Background.Color}"/>
                                </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        </Border>
                        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
                          <Setter TargetName="CenterText" Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

Edit:

The idea is to change the behavior functionality (a small change) when the row is selected in the ListBox

Comment: So if I'm reading this right, you just want to change the background color of the Item when the item is selected?

Comment: Bit unclear. Could you elaborate the first paragraph?

Comment: I am not trying to change the background color, I am trying to change a value of a property of type color (could be any type) when the item is selected, this property is used in the code in function "DrowImage".
What you see in the example is an attepmt to change it using another control and binding to that control (that didn't work).
My first attempt was to put the DragToCenter in the trigger but it didn't recognize it.